# How to use Configuration.assertionMode = AssertionMode.SOFT; with mixed framework (selenium + selenide)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenide

I'm working with old framefork which uses selenium, but now i'm trying use Selenide.
BaseTest has listeners:

```
@Listeners({TestMethodListener.class, TestListener.class, TimeoutTransformer.class, SoftAsserts.class})
```

And in @BeforeSuite
Configuration.assertionMode = AssertionMode.SOFT

I always getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using soft asserts, but without @SoftAsserts annotation
```

To use Selenide methods i just setting current driver to WebDriverRunner
WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver)

Does anyone had similar problems?